# Stable homotopy type of a space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

Is it possible to get a space (may not be a CW complex) which has some non zero homotopy group, but all of whose stable homotopy groups are zero?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does https://mathoverflow.net/a/73702/4194 answer your question?

Comment: Thanks a lot John. Yes, connecting singular homology with Elienberg Maclane spectra in Whitehead style, it totally gives what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll turn my comment into an answer: [David White's answer to a question on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/73702/4194) provides a space $X$ which is not contractible, but its suspension is. In particular, $\pi_1(X) \not \cong 0$, but all of the homotopy groups of $\Sigma X$ are zero, and hence the stable homotopy groups of $X$ are zero.